# Redmine doesn't access VisualSVN repository

Tags: svn, redmine, visualsvn-server, bitnami

I'm trying to keep on VisualSVN Server because it works great and has a nice admin UI.

Using TortoiseSVN, I can properly check out from it using the URL `http://myhost:90/svn/HikariKrumo/`

But I can't get Redmine to do the same. If I use this same exact URL and go to Repository page, I get error message `The entry or revision was not found in the repository.`

VisualSVN Server doesn't support `svn://` protocol. Redmine should support SVN over HTTP(s), but it's not working.

Comment: The error message is `The entry or revision was not found in the repository.`. They are all in the same PC.

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure Redmine repository to use `http://myhost:90/repository-name`? Redmine uses "svn" command to get the required info in the repository. Could you try to checkout your repository from the BitNami Redmine command line?

```
Start -> Program Files -> BitNami Redmine -> Use Redmine

> svn checkout http://myhost:90/repository-name
```

Note that you should specify the repository name in the URL too. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your repository settings inside redmine you have to enter the path to yor local repository you've checked out on your local disc.